# ImportError: No module named opencv.cv

Tags: python, linux, opencv, linux-mint

I installed opencv on Linux Mint using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

When I attempt to import the opencv module using:

```
from opencv.cv import *
```

I receive the error:

```
from opencv.cv import *
ImportError: No module named opencv.cv
```

Any idea why this error is occurring and how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
import cv
```

as in [examples](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html) or

```
from cv import *
```

Comment: The example I was following was quite old. It appears the module name changed from open.cv to cv. Also, I needed to add python to my Linux path.